# Is there a dynamic pathing file, or any way all users can find the path downloaded in different directory?

Tags: pandas, github, path, operating-system, filepath

I am working on a project and multiple people is commiting in a single file. We want to create a dynamic path so if each one of us has the file in different directories  doesnt matter and find the file.

Tried using os, but its very specific

declare a variable with the dynamic path, and solve the problem of editing the file each time one of us edit the file.

path = universalpath/data.json

Comment: The version with the variable is no option for you? Are all of you using the same operating system and if so, which is it and are you downloading with a browser? Maybe from that info someone could suggest another solution. You know with the variable version you could create a small python file that just sets the path. Everyone of you could import the file in the python script(s) you are using and could leave the script untouched but still be able to change the path. That's how I work in scripts I use on different systems.

Comment: This way, if someone changes anything in the python code, you only could exchange the script by the new version, but if it still uses the path-script, it would work in everyone's environment without having to customize it for your environment.